# I had split 420 yuv file to 420_y 420_u 420_v, how to open the three files?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I simplest splite yuv 420 file to three files:y, u, v, by use code:

```html
int simplest_yuv420_split(char *url, int w, int h,int num){
    FILE *fp=fopen(url,"rb+");  
    FILE *fp1=fopen("output_420_y.y","wb+");  
    FILE *fp2=fopen("output_420_u.y","wb+");  
    FILE *fp3=fopen("output_420_v.y","wb+");  
  
    unsigned char *pic=(unsigned char *)malloc(w*h*3/2);  
  
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){  
  
        fread(pic,1,w*h*3/2,fp);  
        //Y  
        fwrite(pic,1,w*h,fp1);  
        //U  
        fwrite(pic+w*h,1,w*h/4,fp2);  
        //V  
        fwrite(pic+w*h*5/4,1,w*h/4,fp3);  
    }  
  
    free(pic);  
    fclose(fp);  
    fclose(fp1);  
    fclose(fp2);  
    fclose(fp3);  
  
    return 0;  
}
```

I can open the original file by ffplay using commend 
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 640x360 -i graybar_640x360.yuv

now I want to open the splited file output_420_y.y

When I run commend 
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 256x256 -i output_420_v.y

show error :
[rawvideo @ 0x7fab5283ea00] Invalid buffer size, packet size 16384 < expected frame_size 98304

I know this means the file output_420_v.y is part of original as 1/6.

anyone can show me how to open this?

thanks.

Comment: I would have thought that, now you have separated Y, U and V, you will have 3 separate grey images. So you would view the Y channel as size 640x360 with pixel format `gray`. The U and V channel as size 320x180 and `gray`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, I have three separated files, but I cant open them, do you know how to open them by use ffplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mark Setchell
I use the below commend is ok.
 ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray -video_size 128*128 -i output_420_v.y

Answer (score 0):

on Linux I found vooya to be good for opening single channel (y or u or v) files easily.

Comment: vooya needs HKD 202.29,it's too expensive, thanks.
And I want to learn video by open source library. 
And I choose ffmpeg to develop.
I use ffplay to open this gray picture by below commend:
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray -video_size 128*128 -i output_420_v.y
thank very much.